# Plotting lines at angle interval

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
for index in range(9):
    m = np.tan(index * 20 * np.pi / 180)
    plt.plot([center[0] - 10, center[0] + 10], [center[1] - 10 * m, center[1] + 10 * m])
```

I'm trying to draw a line every 20 degrees (cartesian, x axis is the start and rotate 20 degrees counterclockwise) between 0 and 180, but when I look at the result of this, the lines are pinched near the x axis and do not appear to have the same angle between them like they should

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your issue. Are you using a polar plot? what is `center`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cartesian coordinates x and y of a circle are expressed by sine and cosine, so you can simply use them and multiply the results by the length of the line which should rotate.
Add this to the center coordinates.

E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

center = [5, 3]
L = np.array([-10, 10])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect(1)
for a in range(0, 180, 20):
    phi = np.deg2rad(a)
    x = center[0] + np.cos(phi) * L
    y = center[1] + np.sin(phi) * L
    ax.plot(x, y)
```

[image]